# How can I use dd to make a Windows 7 USB installer in Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, windows, dd

Why didn't `dd` make a bootable Windows USB stick?

Has anyone tried to burn a Windows 7 USB installer in Ubuntu?

Usually I run `dd` to burn linux ISOs, and I thought it would work for Windows 7, but the stick I burned with `dd` doesn't boot up on my Thinkpad T42.

The `dd` command ran successfully, so why didn't it work? Do you think the boot information wasn't recorded into the USB stick correctly?

```
dd if=SW_DVD5_Win_Pro_7w_SP1_32BIT_ChnSimp_-2_MLF_X17-59520.ISO of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
```

Comment: windows resets the USB during boot. It has to be specifically modified in order to boot.

Comment: Hi, are all windows ISOs regular ones? or just that windows 7 is a regular one?

Comment: This question seems to be about Windows ISOs. Is there an Ubuntu question here?

Comment: i don't think it is duplicated because this topic is about dd command.

Comment: @dsstorefile would you care to elaborate your comment into an answer?

Comment: You have to **extract** and to some extend modify the structure from the Windows iso files to create working USB boot drives. This is different from [hybrid iso files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/isohybrid), which work when **cloned** to DVD disks as well as to USB drives. (Most but not all current linux iso files are hybrid iso files. Many linux iso files are treated with `isohybrid`, but it does not work to treat Windows iso files that way.)