# Is it possible to clone a windows 7 usb installer with dd command

Tags: usb, windows-7, dd, clone

A friend of mine might lend me a windows 7 installer (usb stick). I want to know if I can clone it using the dd command to make another bootable win 7 usb installer.

If not, wich other method do you suggest?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I realize now that my question is not directly ubuntu related. It is more generally linux-related. You may tell me and I will delete it.

Comment: I see now a similar question here:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010468/how-can-i-use-dd-to-make-a-windows-7-usb-installer-in-ubuntu?rq=1. It seems that it is not possible.

Comment: Not sure why you want Windows 7, but what you want worked for me: sudo dd if=/dev/sdx of=/dev/sdy where sdx is your friends stick and sdy is the target stick.

Comment: The object is to clone an existing Windows USB installer not a Windows ISO file. What you want will work.